# Show warning window when closing app?

Tags: window-management, pantheon, window-manager

Background: I run code (Python) using SublimeText (ST). Sometimes I forget I have a script running and close the editor, which obviously kills whatever process is running.

I'd like to somehow prevent a given app from closing by displaying a dialog to confirm first.

The idea is to prevent me accidentally closing an app (ST specifically) with a process still running.

Is this possible at all with Pantheon?

---

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182914/how-to-disable-closing-a-window) is a *somewhat similar* question in AskUbuntu.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this qualifies as feature request for [Gala](https://launchpad.net/gala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elementary apps are still in the process of standardization and I don't believe there are any hooks to easily add the feature you seek without rebuilding your own version of the software from the source. But, hey, if you do it, push the code upstream so that other developers can use it!